# Как сделать чтобы только определённый id мог использовать ту или иную команду

Tags: python, бот, discord

И так недавно я начал учить **Python** для создания **своего бота** для **Discord** на **Discrod.py.** Спустя много попыток мне удалось запустить его и добавить на сервер. Я немного подучил **Python** и начал добавлять **модули** и **команды**. На данный момент **бот** имеет **6 команд** и  **2 эвента.** Так вот мне бы хотелось бы узнать **как сделать так что бы только определённый пользователь мог использовать определённые команды.** Я уже пытался так сделать, но с id не вышло из-за того, что я не понял как его записывать по этому я сделал через ник, а это не надёжно. Хотелось бы узнать решение и получить критику по поводу кода. Ведь я начинающий и явно написал всего бота не так.

Что же вот тут нужно сделать ограничение:

```
@bot.command()
async def botrestart(ctx):

    author = ctx.message.author.name
    if author == "HellCat":
        global cats
        cats = []
        await ctx.send("Bot restarted")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You don't have any rights to this comannd!")

@bot.command() 
async def addcat(ctx, arg): 
    
    cats.append(arg)

@bot.command()
async def cats(ctx): 
    
    await ctx.send(f"Cats: {cats}")
```

**Создал команду botrestart что бы объявить о переменной cats как о списке, внутри commands.**
*То есть грубо говоря это работает так: $botrestart - Создаёт переменную 'cats' с типом данных list. $addcat (arg) добавляет в конец списка 'cats' аргумент команды. И $cats Выводит список всех котов собственно.*

Так вот в этом прекрасном коде вы можете заметить функцию "if" с помощью который я сделал возможность только тем у кого ник "HellCat" использовать эту команду. А мне нужно что бы только лично Я то то есть мой id мог использовать эту команду.

Что же буду рад любой помощи и критике по поводу кода.

**Вот кстати и весь код:**

```
import json
import requests
import discord
import asyncio
from array import *
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'я не на столько глуп)'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
# $help


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   
    print('Bot connected')
# Уведомление о успешном подключении бота

@bot.command()
async def botrestart(ctx):

    author = ctx.message.author.name
    if author == "HellCat":
        global cats
        cats = []
        await ctx.send("Bot restarted")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You don't have any rights to this comannd!")

@bot.command() 
async def addcat(ctx, arg): # Создаём функцию и передаём аргумент ctx.
    cats.append(arg)

@bot.command()
async def cats(ctx):
    
    await ctx.send(f"cats: {cats}") 

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx): # Создаём функцию и передаём аргумент ctx.
    author = ctx.message.author # Объявляем переменную author и записываем туда информацию об авторе.

    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}!') # Выводим сообщение с упоминанием автора, обращаясь к переменной author.

@bot.command(pass_context=True)  # разрешаем передавать агрументы
async def test(ctx, arg):  # создаем асинхронную фунцию бота
   
    await ctx.send(arg)  # отправляем обратно аргумент
# Команда $test. Повторяет аргумент пользывателя 

@bot.command()
async def fox(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/fox') # Get-запрос
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) # Извлекаем JSON

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Random Fox') # Создание Embed'a
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a
    await ctx.send(embed = embed) # Отправляем Embed
# Команда $fox. Отпровляет рандомную лису.




bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Заменить ```author.name``` на ```author.id``` пробовали?

Comment: Советую открыть официальную документацию и почитать про доступные атрибуты

Comment: @Nobody Я пробовал заменить на ctx.message.author, такая функция существует но при проверке мой id и id в переменной author не совпадают.

Comment: ID - просто набор чисел (если вдруг вы делаете проверку через имя#номер)

Comment: @Nobody Я нашёл решение проблемы. Id записывается как int а в сравнение я ставил str. Но спасибо вам за подсказку про ID.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение.
Проблема была в том что при сравнении я указывал мой id как str а он записывался как int.
Что же я всё ещё жду критики по поводу всего кода.

Comment: Здесь вам помогают исправить ошибки в работе кода, а не код ревью делают